# Hide second list item Jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have this script: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9U8bs/4/)

If you type something you will see Google suggestions. If you go down in the list using the arrow keys and select some other suggestion it will give you a second list. This is where my problem starts, because if you then go down with the arrow key it will select the first item in the list which is already in the input. I would like it to go to the second item, so my idea is (after the first suggestions) to HIDE the first suggestion in the list. I have no idea on how to do this. (I could use event 'hide' but that (I think) would cause problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like that?

http://jsfiddle.net/9U8bs/5/

```
if(item.suggestion.data != $('#searchbox').val()){
    return {
        label: item.suggestion.data,
        value: item.suggestion.data
    };
}
```

Just check if the element matches the value of the `#searchbox`.
I think that is much prettier and cleaner than just hiding the first element.

Comment: Thanks:) (I really should take 'the' js course instead of doing this freestyle..)